# Ключ с наименьшим значением

Tags: python

Имеется список с несколькими ключами к словарю. Необходимо вывести тот ключ,  который имеет наименьшее значение.

Comment: Список где? Необходимо кому?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример входных-выходных данных. Лично мне непонятно, как связаны словари и списки в Вашем вопросе. Может, Вам просто подойдёт функция `min()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
slovar = dict(

    key1 =  3,
    key2 =  6,
    key3 = -2,
    key4 =  0,
    key5 =  1,
    key6 =  7,
    key7 =  6,
    )

spisok = ['key2', 'key5', 'key6']

result = min(spisok, key=lambda k: slovar[k])

print(result)
```